Prove that a trigonometric polynomial has 2n roots
$0<a_0<a_1<a_2<...<a_n$
Prove:$$a_0+a_1\cos\theta+...+a_n\cos n\theta $$
has 2n distinct roots in $(0,2\pi)$
This is a question in my textbook,the author leaves a hint.That is we should firstly prove that
$$P_n(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k z^k  \ has  \ n \ roots \ in \ B(0,1),$$
B(0,1)={$z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1$}.
I don't know how to prove this,may I use Rouche theorem or argument principle?
I have almost no ideas at all.

It is not clear whether your question is how to prove the hint, or how do derive the claim from it.

Does this answer your question? Showing that the roots of a polynomial with descending positive coefficients lie in the unit disc. (found using the MSE search engine).
